# Eucalyptus 3.4.2 CentOS 6 demo root password

Tags: centos6, eucalyptus

I installed cloud-in-a-box/fastrack of Eucalyptus and am able to create instance and log into it. But when trying sudo, sudo su - or login in as root I'm asked for a password. I'm not sure what the password might be. Does anyone know what the default password for the Image is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is how the image is designed.  It uses the cloud-user account only and has no root access, nor does it allow sudo.

There are other starter images available that can be "installed" that have sudo as root enabled.  In those cases you simply issue

```
sudo su -
```

and you become root.

To see what is easily available use:

```
eustore-describe-images
```

As a note, some of the other starter images have different accounts (not cloud-user), such as ec2-user.  If you don't know which account to use simply try to ssh into the instance as root and it will usually get a message back telling you:

```
Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. Which other image did you use to get ec2-user?

Comment: I have been playing the CentOS 6.4 image, and the Fedora 18 image.  You can get a summary of the configurations of the listed images from this page: https://github.com/eucalyptus/eucalyptus/wiki/Starter-Images

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a password on the root account in that image. Regardless, the recommended way to log into instances is by creating an SSH key (`euca-create-keypair KEYNAME >KEYNAME.pem`), specifying it when running an instance (`euca-run-instance -k KEYNAME`), and then logging in using the key generated (`ssh -i KEYNAME.pem root@INSTANCE-IP`). You'll probably have to change the permissions on that `.pem` file before SSH will allows you to use it (`chmod 0600 KEYNAME.pem`). The instance obtains the public portion of the key from the cloud at boot time and adds it to the authorized_keys file.

Comment: Hi dmitrii I'll try that today. I created a keypair using the web interface. I logged into web eucalyptus console created keypair downloaded it and added it to the instance before launch

Comment: I tried, I'm getting the same issue. I wonder if the version of CentOS 6 demo is messed up.